# How much time is spent on computation for limited while-loops using end's condition restriction MSC01-J (SonarQube)

Tags: java, sonarqube

According to the [MSC01-J](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/java/MSC01-J.+Do+not+use+an+empty+infinite+loop)

> An infinite loop is one that will never end while the program is running, i.e., you have to kill the program to get out of the loop. Whether it is by meeting the loop's end condition or via a break, every loop should have an end condition.

This criterium is used by [SonarQube](https://www.sonarqube.org/) to detect some suspicion points (a.k.a, bad smells) that can cause and impact the application in security aspects.

So, the recommendation is to use `ends-loop` or loop that has a Boolean condition to be break it.

Using a controlled while-loop with `isSuccess` condition as showed below, how much time is spent about `run()` method below ?

```java
    @Override
    public void run() throws InterrupException{
        int i = 0;
        int k = 3000 /*k is 3 seconds*/

        boolean isSuccess = true;
        while( isSuccess ){
            i++;
            isSuccess = i < Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            Thread.sleep( k );

            doSomething();

       }
    }
```

This issue is related to *T(n)* for *Integer.MAX_VALUE*, where  *n=Integer.MAX_VALUE* ?

How much time we can ensure before the *run()* thread being stopped, in days, months or years ? Consider for this case CPU and Hardware Time constant (edited)

Any answer is very appreciated!

Comment: Time is not an absolute metric. It depends from cpu and hardware characteristics. What is you goal? Whend do you want to stop the loop?
Do you want only delete sonar warning?

Comment: @SimoneCasamassa this extracted code is used in production and should be not break for any condition. But, I would like to use this Sonar recommendation because the applications is very critical and any new feature that can improved it is a good choice. I edit the question about CPU and HW constraints

Comment: If you work in production I see another dangerous. An infinite looop is critical because if your code launches an exception in the loop you can't restart the loop without application stop and start. In general you could use a boolean variable to determinate stop or start of cycle and you could change the variable value at runtime from external config file or from api rest for example. In this way you have an instance variable to control the loop. But you have to check with a try catch the loop execution to handle the occurrence

Comment: @SimoneCasamassa yeap, this a problem that I must resolve in the future. But it is a legacy application, another approach is to use `ScheduledExecutorService` in the place infinite loops, but it requires a bigger refactory and change only the loop constraints not change the application at all

Answer (score 0):

After comments I could suggest you the following workaround:

```
 private Boolean isSuccess = true; 

 @Override
    public void run() throws InterrupException{
        int i = 0;
        int k = 3000 /*k is 3 seconds*/

        while( isSuccess ){
            i++;
            Thread.sleep( k );

            doSomething();

       }
    }
```

This way you should resolve the warning because you have a managed condition in the object.